# how to resolve npm start error in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npx, npm-start, react-scripts

After i ran

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

using my vscode integrated terminal all dependencies and node_modules are installed but when i ran

```
npm start
```

it doesn't work instead i get this error

```
> milkai@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'completed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

any help and guidance you can give me i just stared learning react and i cant figure it out

i tried deleting and reinstalling the node_modules, i also installed the react app globally using cmd

Comment: Please check if you have an `&` in your project's path. If yes, this happens.

Comment: Try running it from command prompt.